# Editing saved Multiple Checkbox selections in Django

Tags: sql, django, forms, checkbox

Whats the best way of performing the save because at the moment. When it comes to editing, I'm not getting the saved responses to populate the form. Other fields such as drop downs are fine. Is there somehthing I should do in the view to make this work? Here is my view:

```
def populateaboutme(request):
    extractlinkedindata(request)    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AboutMeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            today = datetime.date.today()
            currentYYMMDD = today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            model_instance = form.save(commit=False)
            model_instance.save()
            request.session["AboutMe_id"] = model_instance.pk
            StoreImage(settings.STATIC_ROOT, str(request.session["fotoloc"]), '.jpg', str(request.session["AboutMe_id"]))
            return redirect('/dashboard/')
    else:
        myid = request.session["AboutMe_id"]
        if not myid:
            form = AboutMeForm()
        else:
            aboutme = AboutMe.objects.get(pk=int(myid))
            form = AboutMeForm(instance=aboutme)            


    return render(request, "aboutme.html", {'form': form})

Here are the models:

    class AboutMe(models.Model):
        MyRelationshipIntent       = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

and the forms:

```
class AboutMeForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:     
            model = AboutMe
        exclude = () 

        MyRelationshipIntent = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=RELATIONSHIPINTENT_CHOICES,widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

  RELATIONSHIPINTENT_CHOICES = (
   ('JL', 'Just Looking'),
   ('FL', 'Looking for friendship'),
   ('FN', 'Looking for fun'),
   ('FL', 'Looking for a relationship'),
)
```

Comment: Show me the models.py and forms.py and I'll give a more complete answer

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the initial option on the form:

```
form = AboutMeForm(initial={'name': aboutme.name})
```

The instance= you are using is what you need to use when saving to tell django this isn't a new object:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AboutMeForm(request.POST, instance=aboutme)
```

Now using instance *can* give the initial values as well, but only when using a modelform, and you still need it for the saving part.

**Edit**

It took me a while to notice it because I was focusing on the form, but the problem you are having stems, essentially, from the fact that you are using a CharField where you should be using a ManyToManyField. I mean - how would four checked boxes be translated into one CharField and vice-versa? Django can't just guess it. It makes no sense.

You can use a CharField if you somehow add a method to translate it to the checkboxes. But it's also a wrong approach so don't. Instead, I'll give you two solutions, and you'll choose the one you see fit.

The most natural thing to do would be to use a ManyToMany field here, and then tell the django form to use the checkbox field for it (the default would be a multiselect, and if you want you can use a client side plugin to [make that](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/) look [nice as well](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)). Your models would look something like this:

```
class Intent(models.Model): 
    relationship = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class AboutMe(models.Model):
    intents = models.ManyToManyField(Intent)
```

Then you just create four Intent instances for each of the values in your RELATIONSHIPINTENT_CHOICES:

```
rels = ('Just Looking',
'Looking for friendship',
'Looking for fun',
'Looking for a relationship')

for i in rels:
    new = Intent(relationship=i)
    new.save()
```

This is especially good if you think that you might want to add more options later on (and you can create a model on the admin site to ease that proccess instead of the script I wrote up there). If you don't like that solution and you're sure your options would remain the same, another good solution that might suit you is creating a boolean field for each option. Like this:

```
class AboutMe(models.Model)
    jl = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Just Looking')
    fl = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Looking for friendship')
    fn = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Looking for fun')
    fl = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Looking for a relationship')
```

Then you don't even need the widget, because checkbox is the default for boolean fields. After doing this, using `form(instance=aboutme)` and `form(initial={'jl': aboutme.jl})` would both work. I know those might look a little scary and more complex than your simple CharField, but this is the right way to go.

p.s.
Other python tips to keep in mind:

- Don't name your class "AboutMe". That should be the view, not the model. It makes more sense (to me at least) to make it an extension of the built-in User, name it User or give it a similar fitting name (Profile or Account or the sort)
- Field names should not look like class names (check out [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more conventions). So it should be my_relationship_intent. However, that's also a long and wearying name. relationship_intent or simply intents is a lot better.

Comment: I'm trying: form = AboutMeForm(initial={'MyRelationshipStatus': aboutme.MyRelationshipStatus},instance=aboutme) but this doesn't appear to work either. Is this a formatting issue - i.e. values in the table are not stored in a format that be read back to populate checkboxes?

Comment: You are using a choice field, which should be a select box. Where are the checkboxes? If you created them yourself on the template somehow then you obviously can't use the initial={} to populate them (because they are not part of your django form), you'll have to do it manually. However you can also use the Multiple Checkbox widget (look for it in the django docs) and then initial will work

Comment: Really sorry, I used the wrong part of the mode/form to illustrate the problem. I have updated the question to show the use of Multiple Checkbox widgets. The choice field does work just fine....But still there is the question of the Multiple fields not being returned/stored correctly.

Comment: There you go. An updated answer. Hope that clears things up a bit

Comment: Thanks - apologies for the delay. With the first solution, I get the following error: 'File "/home/models.py", line 40, in <module>
    new.save()' which I guess is down to the save command. Where should I best place the code that creates the saving? I cannot get this new model to validate.

Comment: You need to run that script once after rebuilding your scheme. It's not supposed to be in the models.py. It's just a script to create Intent objects with your given option using django's API. If this is confusing you just register Intent with the admin and add them manually

Comment: Thanks - I'm not sure how I would add this to admin - what is the best way of doing that. I've not used the admin.

Comment: Follow the tutorial in the django docs. It's easy and to the point, you"ll pick it up in no time

Comment: THanks. I tried this and now I have the data in the tale, I used my form with a TAG as well as a longer description. In use when I select the checkboxes I get the data saved, but when later instancing the model I don't get the saved data returned. I used the following: 'for tag,des in RELATIONSHIPINTENT_CHOICES:
 new = RelationshipIntent(slug=tag, title=des)
 new.save()'

Comment: I'm finding it hard to understand what you mean just there. You might want to simply update your question with the new information